# UIUISegmentedControls overlap inside UITableView cells after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have UITableView with some cells (settings).

Inside the cell I create a UISegmentedControl programmatically:

```
class SettingsCell: UITableViewCell { 
var segDist : UISegmentedControl? = nil ...

var sectionType: SectionType?{
    didSet{
        guard let sectionType = sectionType else {return}
        
        textLabel?.text = sectionType.description
 

        switch sectionType.containsSegmented{
            case .DISTANCE:
            if (segDist == nil){
                segDist = makeSegmentedControl(items:["yrds","m"], segmentIndex:  SettingsManager.shared.getRangeUnitIndex() - 1, action: #selector(handleSegmentedControlActionDistance))}
```

and so on for every cell. Everything works fine

[image]

, but if l scroll down and up several times (5-10), my segmentedControls can overlap:

[image]

Seems like UISegmentedControl from second row is created in the first and vice versa.   How can I avoid it?

Comment: Cells are reused. What's `makeSegmentedControl(...)`?

Comment: You should have ONE segmented control in your cell and set the segment titles... don't create and add a new control every time.

Answer (score -1):

> Create segment control in your cell UI or code so that it will get
> refresh for each new cell as donMag mention

if you need help in that setup please share your implementation